# How is this iTunes album art blur effect achieved?

Tags: ios, css, blur

Images for reference:

[image: Blurred background 1]

[image: Blurred background 2]

From clicking around on other albums, it appears that the album art is possibly zoomed in on and then a blurred mask is applied over top? Does anyone know how this kind of effect is achieved? It's a really good looking blur and transparency combination.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle with an example:

(The top is the blur effect and the bottom is the original image)

https://jsfiddle.net/LmyepLac/

The useful part is:

```
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
```

To create a blur effect, can change from 20px to suit your needs :)

Comment: Soon, the headers will be removed and you will only need to use `filter`.

Comment: Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/LmyepLac/1/

Comment: @peanut yes that's true, thanks :)

Comment: [Here's a much simpler way of doing the blur.](https://jsfiddle.net/Purpur/LmyepLac/2/)